# How can I extend lower level objects when using the Knockout Mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

If I have multilevel data such as:

```
{"tabs": [
     "rows": [{
        "id": 200,
        "name": "B"},
    {
        "id": 300,
        "name": "C"}]},...
```

I understand that I can extend the tabs using the following code:

```
var myTabExtensions = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.addRow = function() {
        var rowID = this.rows().length + 1;
        this.rows.push(new Row(rowID, 'row ' + rowID));
    }.bind(this);
};

var mapping = {
    'tabs': {
        key: function(data) {
            return data.id;
        },
        create: function(options) {
            return new myTabExtensions(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

...but how can I extend each row (which is not at the root)?

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqFxZ/7/) with a little bit more detail. In that example, I'm trying to enable the commented addRowFirst link in the HTML.

Comment: For some reason your fiddle isn't working for me.  The mapping plugin isn't loading correctly.

Comment: Try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/fqFxZ/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each mapping you do, the mapping object you pass in (the second parameter) only works for the object in the first parameter.  For nested mappings, you need to provide a new mapping object.

Since your `myTabModel` is trying to map the data associated with the tab, it will use the mapping object to provide the mappings.  Since it's empty, it doesn't handle your rows.  Move your `rows` mappings there.

```
var myTabModel = function(data) {
    // use this mapping object to map our tab
    var mapping = {
        'rows': {
            key: function(data) {
                return data.id;
            },
            create: function(options) {
                return new myRowModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);

    this.addRow = function() {
        var rowID = this.rows().length + 1;
        this.rows.push(new Row(rowID, 'row ' + rowID));
    }.bind(this);
};
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqFxZ/9/)

Comment: Sorry, the wording of my explanation was poor, hopefully the example explains itself.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. The code makes sense. I've put a slight updated fiddle out at: http://jsfiddle.net/fqFxZ/11/ 
(Any remaining issue were with my code)